# Using Classes in a Session Variable

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I am attempting to store a class as a session variable.

I have an App_Code page called "SVars.cs" that is designed to hold all session variables for the various pages using get and set.

For example:

```
public static int Account { 
    get { return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Account"];} 
    set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Account"] = value; } 
}
```

This allows me to access Account by commands like this:

```
SVars.Account = "TestUser";
Test.Text = Svars.Account;
```

Now, my question is, is there a way to do this when I store a Class as a session variable?

It seems that I can store the class, but I can only get it to work if I use the whole class and not any functions or variables within the class.  So, an option is to make a new instance of the class then save it out.  But, this is especially clunky on some of my pages.

```
public static myClass Compass {
    get { return (myClass)HttpContext.Current.Session["Compass"]; } 
    set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Compass"] = value; } 
}
```

I would like to be able to access the members of myClass directly and affect them.

Like:

```
SVars.Compass.angle = 34;
SVars.Compass.calculate();
Textbox.Text = "The direction is " + SVars.Compass.direction;
```

Etc,
But, when I try this, I get an error:

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'SVars.Compass.get'

Comment: Your code should work. Are you sure you have declared the property as `static`?

Comment: Are you referring to the code that I don't want? I'm going to delete that as again, it is what I don't want to do.  The other properties are NOT static.  When I attempted to make them static it caused an different error.  "Static member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

Comment: Actually.  Thanks for the comment.  It allowed me to look through and I found that it was marked static where it shouldn't have been and was not static elsewhere...  Anyway, my question is solved.